# Content provider URI matcher

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

There is distinct recomendation in documentation for defining all uris while implementing [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). But I'm confused with URI matcher part: for example, I've got package `org.company.example`, table named 'items', then I define

```
 public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = 
  Uri.parse("content://org.company.example.sampleprovider/items");
```

And what authority part should I use for matching URIs  in static init:

```
 private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

  static {
   uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
   uriMatcher.addURI("what goes here?", "items", ITEM);
   uriMatcher.addURI("what goes here?", "items/#", ITEM_ID);
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "org.company.example.sampleprovider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME);
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static {
   uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
   uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "items", ITEM);
   uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "items/#", ITEM_ID);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't my CONTENT_URI contain path to table?

Comment: You do not have to, but it is possible. Its for you to decide. My content providers are already named like "BooksProvider" so I do not need to add the extra "/books" to make clear to the user what the provider does.